# How to output Javascript from PHP files with PHP variables embedded in JS code?

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to move JS code snippets out of PHP files and into their own files in order to make code a lot cleaner and easier to maintain.  For example, I have this function:

```
function load_script($fieldname)
{
  return
  'var help = function () {alert(' . '"EDITOR HELP:\n\n' . 
                                     'blah blah.\n\n' . 
                                     'more blah blah.\n\n' . 
                                     ');}' . "\n" .
  'var options = { handler: help, title: "Editor help" };' . "\n" .
  'var converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();' . "\n" .
  'var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter, "-'.$fieldname.'", options);' . "\n" .
  'editor.run();' . "\n";
}
```

Notice the `$fieldname` PHP variable.

The idea is to store the JS portion in a .js file.  Then I'd read it in as plain text in order to output in the return statement.  In other words, something like this:

```
function load_script($fieldname)
{
  $output = file_get_contents("load_script.js");
  return $output;
}
```

Obviously the problem is that this would not substitute `$fieldname` with the corresponding value.

My current thought on this is to run `$output` through string subsitution:

```
function load_script($fieldname)
{
  $output = file_get_contents("load_script.js");
  $output = str_replace("some_unique_identifier", $fieldname, $output);
  return $output;
}
```

Is there a better approach?

EDIT:

I should add some of the motivation behind this:

First, the example given is ugly and hard to maintain for anything but the simplest JS snippets.  Lots of room for mistakes.

Second, editors aren't very helpful in terms of checking syntax and highlighting when you mix things up this way.

Third, having JS live on its own files makes it easier to run a minification script that crunches on the entire site (so you don't have to manually maintain minification).

Comment: If you use a templates in php spit out JS data (arrays or dicts) you need with JSON..

Comment: don't embed raw php-provided data in JS code blocks. always json_encode() it first, so you produce syntactically valid JS. One syntax error and the entire JS code block gets killed.

Comment: @MarcB: Can I ask you to expand on that.  Isn't json_encode("my string") == "my string"?  Unless the variable containing the string accidentally becomes an array I don't see how the raw PHP string variable could blow-up the JS code block.  In other words, if json_encode() is used you'll get the JSON equivalent of the array, which will blow-up the JS anyway because it is expecting a string.  Maybe I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: @martin's: `<?php $name = "Miles O'Brien"; ?> var x = '<?php echo $name ?>'`. oops. unterminated string literal. Just because ONE value doesn't cause a problem, doesn't mean that ALL values won't cause problems. calling json_encode is trivial overhead for guaranteeing you won't break the JS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a template engine to do this (such as Smarty for instance). Simply write your JS files using the template variables where your PHP variables would be, and load them through PHP.

You could even roll your own simple one. Something like:

```
// in JS file:
function myFunc() {
    alert("hello %s");
}

// in PHP file:
<?PHP
    //... code to open JS file and load into string....
    echo sprintf($contentsOfJSFile, "John Doe");
?>

RESULTING OUTPUT: 

function myFunc() {
    alert("hello John Doe");
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of using sprintf() in cases where there's a single variable to populate.  This is very clean.  It's one of those "why didn't I think of that" things.  However, in the case of a script with multiple variables I'd prefer substring-matched substitution because of the potential risk of messing things up with sprintf() due to the order of the arguments.

Comment: In that case, you could use the same concept you listed as part of yoru question with str_replace(). I would just beef it up a bit by adding it to a loop that loops over an array where the key is the var name in the JS template, and the value is what you replace.

Answer (score 1):

As someone already mentioned, A JS file is just as HTML, which in turn, is just like a PHP file. So create you javascript file like this

```
<?php
//my_script.php
?>

<script>
 var foo = "<?= $bar ?>";
</script>
```

And then, in your php:

```
$bar = 'some value';
include('my_script.php');
```

Comment: this is pretty clean BUT it has php embedded in the "html" and not vice versa... this is fine for simple things but can cause problems in complex applications where you want your view code separated from your logic code. often you want your php to spit out html without being enclosed in it, for a number of good reasons

Comment: @speakingcode: I usually have the snippet above as my view files. I suppose there might be reasons where you wouldn't want that in which case you'd probably want to go with some templating engine.

Comment: I would prefer "clean" JS in a JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not really, or, at least, not out of the box. There are some clever solutions such as Backbone which might make your task easier or more sane, but might also require a rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutsehll, outputting js is the same as outputting html. You can embed php variables, but you're subject to the same rules as far as escaping quotes and literals vs references. It can get ugly and tedious pretty quickly.

What I do depends on the JS and the number of variables. Sometimes I make strings for all my js and then glue them together, like

```
$js_function_pt1 = "var help = function() { ..."
$js_function_pt2 = "..."

return $js_function_pt1 + $fieldname + $js_function_pt2 + ....
```

if you can keep all single quotes in your js, you have a little extra luxury in that you can enclose your js output in double qoutes, and then variable references from php will interpreted as variables and evaluated.

```
$output = " var help = function() { alert('blah blah $fieldname') } "
```